# JPA - JSF - Rerendered - Ajax why must i re-start server to see new item was added?

Tags: java, jsf, ejb-3.0

i have problem with load data from Database

i use Primefaces (or other use richfaces) to persist object into database using object - it means when you add object into database object will display on datatable <--- it's use ajax
but problem is here, i can see object on datatable but when i go to other page (ex. i add new item into item table and go to item list page to view new item) but i can't see new item was added, i must stop and start server again and it display in item list?

What's happen with it?

Anyone have any solution please help me!

Thank you

P/s: my backin bean using Session Scoped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you aren't reloading the list in session or the DB transaction isn't (auto)committed.

Comment: how can i reload list in session? do i do it in my JSF Backin bean?

Comment: In the action method where you're saving the new item. Do it directly after saving the new item.